# How do I access data from a fetch in a get method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Okay, so I feel like this is way more trivial than it needs to be, but for some reason, I cannot get information out of my "body" when it is passed to the get method. I've tried a number of different ways to access it, but nothing sees to do the trick. Guidance is much appreciate. Below is my code:

```
 ---------------fetch method----------------
  var x = e.target.phone.value;
  var y = e.target.email.value;

  console.log(x); // proper output
  console.log(y); // proper output

  fetch('/api/insert', 
  {
    accept: 'application/json',
    body: {
      phone2: x,
      email2: y
    }
  });
 ------------get method--------------
app.get('/api/insert', (req, res) => {
    const phone = req.body.phone2; <-- Am I accessing the data incorrectly?

    const email = req.body.email2; <-- Am I accessing the data incorrectly?
    console.log(phone); // getting undefined here... Why?
    console.log(email); // and here...
    });
    });
```

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(req)` and `console.log(res)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `req.query.phone2` and `req.query.email2`.

Parameters for a GET request are sent as query parameters on the URL (no body is sent with a GET request) and Express puts query parameters in `req.query`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call it like this:

```
fetch('......')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.movies;
})
.catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
});
```